# Matrix Multiple Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

The following code generates:

[image]

You can see that the first and the second line are centered on the right side of the left brace.

How can I **stick to** the current code **implementing "\begin{matrix}"** and achieve:

1. aligning "a(E)" in both lines to the left
2. aligning "if" to the left

so that two "a"s and "i"s can be aligned together.

[image]

```
\text{when} \left\{\begin{matrix}
a(E)'=\infty, &\text{if }E=\bar{L} \\ 
a(E)'=0, &\text{if }E=0  
\end{matrix}\right.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool: `matrix` centers each cell.

```
\begin{equation*}
\text{when }
\begin{cases}
a(E)'=\infty, &\text{if $E=\bar{L}$} \\ 
a(E)'=0, &\text{if $E=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: demo]